# Is there a version number for Blazor apps?

Tags: github, blazor, blazor-server-side

When I wrote Win Forms apps, there was an AssemblyInfo properties file with the app version number. We set up GitHub to increment that by 1 in each publish. And we then displayed that number in the about box.

Does Blazor (server) have this? And if so:

1. Where is it?
2. How do I read it programatically?
3. Is there an easy way to tell GitHub to auto-increment it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Where is it?

Add a `<Version>` tag to a `<PropertyGroup>` in your project's .csproj file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Version>2.2.38</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

> 2. How do I read it programmatically?

Extension method to read version from the Assembly.

```cs
public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static string GetAssemblyFileVersion(this Assembly _this)
    {
        var attr = _this.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>();
        return attr == null ? "" : attr.Version;
    }
}
```

Read the Assembly's Version

```cs
var version = typeof(SomeTypeInYourProject).Assembly.GetAssemblyFileVersion();
// version == "2.2.38.0"
```

> 3. Is there an easy way to tell GitHub to auto-increment it?

Not sure on this one. Hopefully someone else can help with this one.

Comment: GetAssemblyFileVersion() not found. I'm using Blazor. Is it something else?

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to add the Assembly extension methods I use. They are there now.